# Strange results with Get-ADUser -Filter {displayname -like $displayname}

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to see if a display name is shared by more than one account.

I'm using the code `(Get-ADUser -Filter {displayname -like $name}).Count`.

This sometimes produces the correct result and sometimes produces no result at all. All the accounts are correctly set up with no spaces at the end of their names.

Comment: How does it work using -match rather than -like?

Comment: @I.TDelinquent it won't, `Filter` gets translated to an LDAP filter internally, and LDAP query filters don't support regex

Comment: What is the value of `$name`?

Comment: $name is the full name of the users(s) i.e. "John Smith"

Comment: Then you'll find only exact matches. You need to add `*` wildcards at beginning and/or end of the string for partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {displayname -like $name} | measure | select -ExpandProperty Count
```

This is because when only one user is returned it's not treated as a collection but a single user object.
Using `measure` ([`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-6)) allows you to circumvent this.
If no user is returned you will get `0`, if only one is returned you will get `1` and if multiple users are returned you will get the actual number of users.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when there is only one result, a single object is returned, not a collection. Since the object does not contain a `.Count` property, your statement will return nothing.

You can force the output into a collection by using the array literal (`@()`)

```
(@(Get-ADUser -Filter {displayname -like $name})).Count
```

The above will always return the count of the collection, even if there are one or zero results.

Answer (score 0):

Ansgar,

Would this do what you want?

```
$Filter = "displayname -like $name"
(Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter).Count
```

I seem to remember that the cmdlets don't like variables in the filter's syntax.